# How to retrieve payload on msal:handleRedirectStart?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I need to retrieve the account information which is login into my application. Is there any way to retrieve the payload on msal:handleRedirectStart? If the info is already loaded in the browser the code executed is msal:handleRedirectStart and there's not payload info for it so I cannot retrieve it the same way as on loginSuccess/acquireTokenSuccess.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._subscription = this.broadcastService.msalSubject$.subscribe(
      (subject) => {
        if (
          subject.eventType === 'msal:loginSuccess' ||
          subject.eventType === 'msal:acquireTokenSuccess'
        ) {
          const payload = subject.payload;
          const username = payload.account.name;
          this.userFullName = username;
          this.isLogged = true;
        }
        if (subject.eventType === 'msal:handleRedirectStart') {
            this.isLogged = true;
            // payload is empty
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Thanks for the help